# Configure git to pull into fixed branch

Tags: git

Can I configure git such that

```
git pull
```

will always pull remote:master into my local master branch, regardless of which branch I'm currently on?

Comment: Stack Overflow might be a better place for Git questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `git pull` cannot do that.

The `pull` command is basically a shortcut for `fetch` + `merge`. The first step is to fetch all remote branches into local "remote-tracking" ones; the second step is to merge the appropriate remote-tracking branch into the *current branch*. Since a proper merge requires a working tree, Git does not allow merging into anything else except the currently checked out branch.

You can, however, *fast-forward* branches. If you don't have any local commits in `master` and all merges are going to be fast-forwards, then you can make an alias for:

```
git fetch && git push . origin/master:master
```

This fetches all branches, then pushes the new commits from `origin/master` into `master` in the same repository (here `.` means "this repository"). The same could be done using various other commands, but pushing is a convenient way to ensure that only fast-forwards will happen and no commits will be lost.